# How to fix "MongoSocketException" to external MongoDB with Java?

Tags: java, database, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to connect with my java spring boot server to my external mongoDB with this code:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
                "mongodb+srv://username:password@integrationcourse-7bsmm.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("course");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("UserEntitys");
```

And I'm getting this following error:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: integrationcourse-7bsmm.mongodb.net
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:211) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.initializeSocket(SocketStream.java:75) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:65) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:128) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_191]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: integrationcourse-7bsmm.mongodb.net
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.InetAddress$2.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1324) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1277) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at com.mongodb.ServerAddress.getSocketAddresses(ServerAddress.java:203) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.0-beta2.jar:na]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `java.net.UnknownHostException: integrationcourse-7bsmm.mongodb.net` - Your computer cannot contact that host name. Neither can I, so I would suggest that wherever you are getting those details from is incorrect.

Comment: @NeilLunn I got it straight from the mongodb connection link

Comment: @NeilLunn You can see it here https://ibb.co/thtrHgq

Comment: You mean from Atlas I presume. Did you enable your connection in the whitelist? You certainly did not enable all clients since I cannot connect ( just mean connect and not authenticate ). Also have you checked that the Java Driver version installed with your spring-mongodb version actually supports `mongodb+srv`. There are various things noted very clearly on the Atlas connection page you are pointing to which you should be checking.

Comment: First test is to execute a `ping`. If your computer can not find the host you are trying to connect to your MongDB connection will always fail. Go to your operating system command line and type `ping integrationcourse-7bsmm.mongodb.net`. If that fails your problem is not with your Java application.

Comment: Thank you both very much! I used one older url sample from the atlas, pinged it and then connected to the DB. @cmoetzing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

used one older url sample from the atlas, pinged it and then connected to the DB. as suggested.